# Can internet traffic in a virtual box private browser be tracked?

Tags: security, firefox, web, tracking

I am using Firefox 39 on a virtual os of Ubuntu.

Can internet traffic in private mode (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) be tracked?
If not what is the point of these private modes?

Comment: Primary purpose is to not leave traces on your own computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private mode means that the browser enters a clean slate without cookies (and other forms of stored data) for all connections made through that window and deletes all accumulated cookies (and other forms of stored data) when you close the window. It also keeps no history.

It means that websites and marketers no longer know who you are from your browser's self identification. It also means that other people using the same machine can't see what websites you visited.

In these meanings it's "private".

Someone observing your actual traffic however, e.g. someone controlling your router or a hop in your route or a government overseeing all traffic can still see what you are communicating with whom (if the connection is unencrypted) or at least whom you are communicating with (if the connection is encrypted).